# Is it possible to differentiate between Live and Stage in Silverstripe when using onBeforeWrite?

Tags: silverstripe

In Silverstripe I'm using the method OnBeforeWrite to trigger a function when a page is updated or saved.

Documentation: http://api.silverstripe.org/2.4/cms/SiteTree.html#methodonBeforeWrite

Is there a way I can differentiate between writing to the Stage website ("Save" button) and the Live website ("Save & Publish" button)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. When you save a page SS will always do a `write()`. When you 'save and publish' `doPublish()` is also called. http://api.silverstripe.org/2.4/cms/SiteTree.html#methoddoPublish
2. The `SiteTreeDecorator` also has an `onBeforePublish` method. You may want to look into using that. http://api.silverstripe.org/2.4/sapphire/model/SiteTreeDecorator.html#methodonBeforePublish